# How to extract the first backup id from a shell output to a variable?

Tags: shell, sed, grep, variable

```
[user@laptop ~]$ cf adbr list-backups database
Getting backups of database
Backup ID                                         Time of Backup
bbf4277f-889a-4a9a-9274-683ed6e1553c_1647592205   Fri Mar 18 08:30:05 UTC 2022
bbf4277f-889a-4a9a-9274-683ed6e1553c_1647563402   Fri Mar 18 00:30:02 UTC 2022
bbf4277f-889a-4a9a-9274-683ed6e1553c_1647534606   Thu Mar 17 16:30:06 UTC 2022
bbf4277f-889a-4a9a-9274-683ed6e1553c_1647505803   Thu Mar 17 08:30:03 UTC 2022
bbf4277f-889a-4a9a-9274-683ed6e1553c_1647477003   Thu Mar 17 00:30:03 UTC 2022
```

I would like to get a variable named `BACKUP_ID` set to `bbf4277f-889a-4a9a-9274-683ed6e1553c_1647592205`.

How to do this?

I've managed to get the following to arrive at the correct line:

```
cf adbr list-backups database-pre-prod | sed -n '/Backup ID/{n;p}'
```

but I'm not sure how to get the id out of it into a variable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already figured out how to get the correct line. Now we only need to get the first field of this line.

Using `awk`, storing the result in `$BACKUP_ID`:

```
BACKUP_ID=$(cf adbr list-backups database-pre-prod | sed -n '/Backup ID/{n;p}' | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: You never need sed when you're using awk. `sed -n '/Backup ID/{n;p}' | awk '{ print $1 }'` = `awk 'f{print $1; exit} /Backup ID/{f=1}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
BACKUP_ID=$(cf adbr list-backups database | awk 'NR==3{print $1}')
```